# How to add time to last Sunday ssrs expression?

Tags: reporting-services

How to add the time 23:59:59 pm to the following expression:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-WeekDay(Today), Today)
```

I've tried adding the time

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-WeekDay(Today)+ "23:59:59", Today)
```

The expression is returning me the last Sunday day but I need to add the time somehow

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to subtract a second from tomorrow.

```
=TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.DayOfWeek).AddSeconds(-1)
```

I think if you want to use DATEADD, you'd need one for each interval (Hour, minute and second).